# Not able to render image from API

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am able to fetch the data from API endpoint but am not able to render it to the screen.

This is my App.js component.

```
    function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
      const [img, setImg] = useState([]);

    

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(setData);
  }, []);

  async function fetchImage(name) {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "GET",
      redirect: "follow",
    };
   await fetch(
      `https://avatars.dicebear.com/v2/avataaars/${name}.svg?options[mood][]=angry`,
      requestOptions
    )
      .then((response) => response.text())
      // .then((text)=>setImg(text))
      .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">

      {data.map((details) => {
        return (
          <Card
            key={details.id}
            email={details.email}
            name={details.name}
            image={fetchImage(details.username)}
            phone={details.phone}
            website={details.website}
            company={details.company.name}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is my card component.

```
    export default function Card(props) {
  return (
    <Box
      w="70vw"
      h="250px"
      borderWidth="1px"
      borderColor={"black"}
      overflow="hidden"
      m="2vh auto"
      display={"flex"}
      flexDir="row"
      color="black"
    >
      <Box>
        <Image
          w="20vw"
          h="250px"
          src={props.image}
          bg="gray"
        />
      </Box>

      <Box display='flex' flexDirection={'column'} alignItems='flex-start' ml='2vw' fontSize={'lg'}>
          <Box fontSize={'3xl'} mb='2vw'>{props.name}</Box>
          <Box><strong>Email: </strong>{props.email}</Box>
          <Box><strong>Phone: </strong>{props.phone}</Box>
          <Box><strong>Company: </strong>{props.company}</Box>
          <Box><strong>Website: </strong>{props.website}</Box>
          <Box><strong>Address: </strong>{props.address}</Box>
      </Box>
    </Box>
```

I figured out is returning promise instead of fetched data. If I uncomment the setImg promise, images are fetched continuously but still not rendering. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App.js:

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(setData);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">

      {data.map((details) => {
        return (
          <Card
            key={details.id}
            email={details.email}
            name={details.name}
            username={details.username} // <=== Change image prop to username prop
            phone={details.phone}
            website={details.website}
            company={details.company.name}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Card component:

```
export default function Card(props) {
  const imgURL = `https://avatars.dicebear.com/v2/avataaars/${props?.name}.svg?options[mood][]=angry`
  return (
    <Box
      w="70vw"
      h="250px"
      borderWidth="1px"
      borderColor={"black"}
      overflow="hidden"
      m="2vh auto"
      display={"flex"}
      flexDir="row"
      color="black"
    >
      <Box>
        <Image
          w="20vw"
          h="250px"
          src={imgURL} //<=== This is src img
          bg="gray"
        />
      </Box>

      <Box display='flex' flexDirection={'column'} alignItems='flex-start' ml='2vw' fontSize={'lg'}>
          <Box fontSize={'3xl'} mb='2vw'>{props.name}</Box>
          <Box><strong>Email: </strong>{props.email}</Box>
          <Box><strong>Phone: </strong>{props.phone}</Box>
          <Box><strong>Company: </strong>{props.company}</Box>
          <Box><strong>Website: </strong>{props.website}</Box>
          <Box><strong>Address: </strong>{props.address}</Box>
      </Box>
    </Box>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'r not using the `await fetch(...)` result

In general, don't mix `await` and `then` use one or another

Plus, if api returns image data, you should not convert it to text, but to blob and use `URL.createObjectURL` to create a correct url

```
const response = await fetch(
      `https://avatars.dicebear.com/v2/avataaars/${name}.svg?options[mood][]=angry`,
      requestOptions
    )
const blob = await response.blob();
return URL.createObjectURL(blob)
```

Or use the api url directly if you can:

```
return `https://avatars.dicebear.com/v2/avataaars/${name}.svg?options[mood][]=angry`;
```

But you should use state to store the generated URLs. This code could be used in your `fetchData()` function and add the imageUrl to each item to not refetch on each render

Comment: The second option seems to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The issue is that the `fetchData` function is unconditionally called when rendering the `data` array. When `.then((text)=>setImg(text))` is uncommented it updates state and triggers a rerender. Repeat ad nauseam.

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [img, setImg] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(setData);
  }, []);

  async function fetchImage(name) {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "GET",
      redirect: "follow",
    };
    await fetch(
      `https://avatars.dicebear.com/v2/avataaars/${name}.svg?options[mood][]=angry`,
      requestOptions
    )
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((text)=>setImg(text)) // <-- (2) update state, trigger rerender
      .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((details) => {
        return (
          <Card
            key={details.id}
            email={details.email}
            name={details.name}
            image={fetchImage(details.username)} // <-- (1) immediately invoked!
            phone={details.phone}
            website={details.website}
            company={details.company.name}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Solution

It doesn't appear you need to "fetch" the images, you can simply use a computed image source value. Create a utility function if you want.

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [img, setImg] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(setData);
  }, []);

  // (1) utility function to compute image source string
  const getImageSrc = name => {
    return `https://avatars.dicebear.com/v2/avataaars/${name}.svg?options[mood][]=angry`
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((details) => {
        return (
          <Card
            key={details.id}
            email={details.email}
            name={details.name}
            image={getImageSrc(details.name)} // <-- (2) call utility
            phone={details.phone}
            website={details.website}
            company={details.company.name}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yeah!. That works too. Didn't think of that. Thank you!.